# Arm error A1174E: Data transfer offset 0x00002000 out of range. Permitted values are 0xFFFFF001 to 0x00000FFF

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

I have a simple assembly which generated the following error

Assembly

```
LDR r14,[r12,#0x00002000]
```

Error

```
testspeed.s(23): error: A1174E: Data transfer offset 0x00002000 out of range.  Permitted values are 0xFFFFFF01 to 0x00000FFF
```

Looking up at the [ARM guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0496j/dom1365071831285.html) i see the reason for the error

```
 A1174E: Data transfer offset 0x<val> out of range. Permitted values are 0x<mini> to 0x<maxi>
```

Anyone know what is this `0x<mini>` and `0x<maxi>` ? And where is it set ? Can i control it.

Comment: They're placeholders for the actual values substituted in the error message. In your case `0x<mini>` is replaced with `0xFFFFFF01` and `0x<maxi>` is replaced with `0x00000FFF`. You can change these values, they're a limitation of the ARM architecture. You'll need to rewrite your assembly statement.

Comment: @RossRidge Where can i set these  in my program ? Is there any documentation about these. I cant seem to find anything useful.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say you can't change them.

Comment: The error message told you everything you need to know.  Simply looking up that instruction in the instruction set explains where that limit came from.    The purpose of stack overflow is not to look these things up for you.  infocenter.arm.com has a lot of useful things, arm.com should have been the first place you looked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a limitation of the ARM instruction set. Per [the documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.kui0100a/armasm_cihgjhed.htm):

```
Instruction           Immediate offset     Pre-indexed      Post-indexed     Arch.
ARM, word or byte [1] -4095 to 4095        -4095 to 4095    -4095 to 4095    All
```

(For some reason, the minus signs are missing from the documentation.)

Your offset is too large to be used as an immediate. You'll have to come up with some other way to access the memory, say, by breaking it up into two instructions.

```
ADD r14, r12, #0x00002000
LDR r14, [r14]
```